# Power BI date and measure calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data table in Power BI which has 2 date columns: Date Created, Date Updated. I have a measure of cases which is just a count of cases. I want to create a line graph in which I want to show all the cases created, and all the cases closed but with a common date axis. My problem is if I use Date created as X-axis I get incorrect values for Cases closed as it depends on Date Updated and vice versa. My one solution is to split the graph into two different KPIs, but I wondered if there is a way to create a custom date column/table with the dates from both date created and date updated and show both the measures on that date column. I want the two measures in the image below in the same date axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to create a `CalendarTable` (if you don't have one). Then, create two relationships from your Source Table to the Calendar one :

- First for `CreatedDate`,
- Second for `ClosedDate`.

Switch one of these relationships to inactive. Next, in your measure reactivate it.

Finally, in the chart, use the time from the `CalendarTable`.

```
exampleMeasure = CALCULATE(
  COUNT(SourceTable[SomeColumn]), 
  USERELATIONSHIP(
    'Calendar'[issue_date],
     SourceTable[CloseDate]
  )
)
```

https://dax.guide/userelationship/

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. I was also thinking this but was not able to get it to work, data type mismatch, On dax it shows both columns as date type but wasn't working. After changing data type to date in query editor it worked. Thanks for the assist though. :)